# How to create json with objects as element from mysql multiple rows

Tags: php, mysql, json

Hi I pretty much stuck on creating json using php and mysql. I got lots of similar question and answers here but I cannot get what I want even after spending lots of time.I need my json output from mysql rows to be like

```
{ "application": [ { "ver": "1.0", "name": "myapp1" }, { "ver": "1.2", "name": "myapp2"}]}
```

I used following code for generating json,

```
$result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM btrack_transaction");
$no_of_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
$rows = array();
//retrieve and print every record
while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
$rows[] = array('data' => $r);
}
// now all the rows have been fetched, it can be encoded
echo json_encode($rows);
```

But my output looks like

```
[[ { "ver": "1.0", "name": "myapp1" }, { "ver": "1.2", "name": "myapp2"}]]
```

How can I get the json format that I want .

Thanks in advance ,

Comment: I don't think that's what your output looks like.

Comment: Oh yes, sorry. The output was from $array($r), I mistakenly put the extra bit of code.

Comment: Why did you think you needed `array()`? `$r` is already an array.

Comment: that output wouldn't come from that, either. It comes from using a loop like in my answer, and then `echo json_encode(array($rows))`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
while ($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $rows[] = $r;
}
echo json_encode(array('application' => $rows));
```

You need to get rid of the extra `array('data' => $r)` wrapper around each element (I don't know why that doesn't show up in the output you say you get), and add the `array('application' => $rows)` at the end to add that element.

Comment: Well that works but why am I getting one extra [ ] .How to remove it. Please check my output in http://www.biotrack.net78.net/mobile/transaction.php

Comment: I don't think my answer will do that. It looks like you're doing `$rows[] = array($r);`.

Comment: Maybe you should try **understanding** what you're doing, rather than just randomly adding and removing `array()` calls.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I admire your suggestion and will follow it.